# Как запустить дайджест цикл?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Посоветуйте пожалуйста способ(ы), при помощи которого можно заставить шаблон обновить значения отображаемых переменных.

Есть простейший сайт с двумя страничками и модулем роутинга. Он состоит из главного компонента и двух дочерних. В главном компоненте я сделал переключатель языка. этот переключатель находится вне

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

, а потому доступен на каждой из двух внутренних страничек.

Переключатель языка представляет из себя mat-slide-toggle из стандартной библиотеки материал. Переключатель работает следующим образом:

tpl:

```
<mat-slide-toggle class="toggler-lang" (click)="toggleLang()"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private lang: boolean = false;

    ngOnInit() {
        localStorage.removeItem('isEnLang');
    };

    private toggleLang() {
        this.lang = !this.lang;

        if(this.lang == true) {
            localStorage.isEnLang = 'true';
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('isEnLang');
        }
    };

}
```

то есть если выбран язык английский, то в локалсторадже есть значение, если выбран язык русский, то в локалстородже нет значения.

Проблема в том, что находясь на страничке "Программа", я при помощи переключателя языка меняю язык, но после этого изменения не отображаются. Чтобы изменения отобразились необходимо уйти со странички "Программа" и снова вернуться на неё. Эту последовательность действий можно воспроизвести на [живом примере](http://fh79272k.bget.ru/files/works/agenda_speakers)

Вот ссылка на [gitHub](https://github.com/zlodiak/ng4_agenda_speakers)

Вот так в Компоненте, который соответствуют страничке "Программа" происходит проверка языка:

```
    private isEnLang: boolean;

  constructor() { 
    this.isEnLang = localStorage.isEnLang ? true : false;
    console.log('this.isEnLang', this.isEnLang);
  };
```

Так происходит вывод в шаблоне Программы:

```
<div class="title" *ngIf="line.title">{{ isEnLang ? line?.title_en.trim() : line?.title.trim() }}</div>
```

Comment: Лучше создайте компонент. В компоненте подпишитесь на событие изменения языка. Меняйте выводимы результат через свойство класса. Везде используйте созданный компонент, не надо будет в другие компоненты тащить код. Если интересно - оформлю ответом.

Answer (score 2):

Вам следует делать проверку не в конструкторе, а в одном из [component lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

> Don't fetch data in a component *constructor*. You shouldn't worry that a new component will try to contact a remote server when created under test or before you decide to display it. Constructors should do no more than set the initial local variables to simple values.

`constructor` следует использовать только для создания/инициализации полей класса, например:

```
constructor(private isEnLang: boolean) {};

ngDoCheck() {
    this.isEnLang = localStorage.isEnLang ? true : false;
    console.log('this.isEnLang', this.isEnLang);
}
```

Comment: Вы навели меня на мысль, что я не правильно построил архитектуру. Дело в том, что когда изменяется локалсторадж(па переключатель языка сейчас у мня вносит изменение тольео в локалсторадж), то ни один из хуков в компоненте не срабатывает. Поэтому буду искать не способ пнуть дайджест цикл, а новую архитектуру

Comment: сервисы, rxjs observables

Comment: Да, я создал сервис для глобальных переменных и кажется получилось... но, уверен, это не лучший способ. Потому что в каждый компонент приходится тащить кучу кода, который взаимодействует с этим сервисом...

Comment: сервисы в angular для этого и нужны: > Instead of copying and pasting the same code over and over, you'll create a single reusable data service and inject it into the components that need it.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы руками запустить дайджест цикл тебе необходим класс `ApplicationRef` https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef , который имеет метод `tick()`

`constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef)`

```
someMethod() {
  this.appRef.tick(); // start digest cycle
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Я бы это организовал примерно таким образом.

#### LanguageService

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
export const LANG_RU = 1;
export const LANG_EN = 2;
export class LanguageService {
    lang: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(LANG_RU);
    setLang(l: number) {
        this.lang.next(l);
    }
}
```

#### StorageService

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
export class StorageService {
    program: BehaviorSubject<ProgDay[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    constructor(private _ls: LanguageService) {
        this._ls.lang.subscribe(lang => this.getNewProgram4Lang(lang));
    }
    
    getNewProgram4Lang(lang: number) {
        let p: ProgDay[] = ...// получить программу для соответствующего языка
        this.program.next(p);
    }
}
```

#### ProgramComponent

```
export class ProgramComponent {
    program: ProgDay[];
    constructor(private _ss: StorageService) {
        this._ss.program.subscribe(prog => this.program = prog);
    }
}
```

#### где-то там где живет переключатель языка

```
export class SomeComponent {
    lang: number;
    constructor(private _ls: LanguageService) { }

    setLang(l: number) {  // вызываете в onChange переключателя
        this._ls.setLang(l);
    }
}
```